# IBM System x3550 Server -7978 Keeps turning off when on idle

Tags: windows, hardware, ibm

I have an IBM X3550 7978 installed it few days ago/upgated but i have an issue it keeps shutting down when on idle. I cant identify any issues why this is happening. I went through the event logs and couldn't find any details just a simple shut down command that was applied.

I checked the server controller Light path diagnostics and see the Mem light orange and PS1 as well.

What does that mean? How can i identify whats shutting it down.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiODH.jpg)

Comment: The OS's power management is probably set to shut down when idle. What OS is it running?

Comment: windows server 2008